# Undefined is not a function (AJAX, PHP, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I am very new to `jQuery` and AJAX so I apologise if I am being stupid.

I am receiving an error in my AJAX `jQuery` script.
I am retrieving data via AJAX get to display dynamically on my page. 
The `JSON` file returns an array which must be iterated and displayed in a DIV for each item.
The `JSON` is:

`[{"id":1,
      "user_id":14,
      "title":"The Title",
       "thumbnail":"image.jpg",
       "summary":"summary of post",
       "content":"content info here",
       "category":"Graphic Design",
       "sub_category":"Adobe Photoshop",
       "views":0,
       "published":0,
       "created_at":"2015-04-16 00:09:57",
       "updated_at":"2015-04-16 00:09:57"},   {and so on...}]`

The `jQuery` is:

```html
function retrieveTutorials()
{
 $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/tutorials/retrieve",
     dataType: "json",
     success: function(data){
          var tutorial = ('')
            $.each(data, function(){
            
                     tutorial.append($(  '<div class="generatedbox"><img src="images/tutorial_upload/' + this.thumbnail + '" /><h1>' + this.title + '</h1><p>' + this.summary + '</p><p class="date">' + this.created_at + '</p></div>'))
            });
            
          $("#generated-content").empty().append(tutorial);
            
  },
  error: function() {
   alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
  }
 });
}
```

The error I am currently receiving is "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" which refers to the following section

```html
tutorial.append($(  '<div class="generatedbox"><img src="images/tutorial_upload/' + this.thumbnail + '" /><h1>' + this.title + '</h1><p>' + this.summary + '</p><p class="date">' + this.created_at + '</p></div>'))
```

Any ideas as to where I am going wrong?
I have used very similar code before which worked fine

Comment: what's the  meaning of this  `var tutorial = ('')` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var tutorial = $('<div></div>');
```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still persists.

Comment: You need some selector there, can you check modified version?

Answer (score 2):

You should select any DOM Element and assign it to tutorial variable, something like this:

```
var tutorial = $('someCSSselector');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error because you are calling `.append()` on `('')`. `.append()` is a jQuery function, but `('')` is an empty string, not a jQuery object.

You can do this:

```
var tutorial = $('<div>');
...
$("#generated-content").empty().append(tutorial.html());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define your `div` object first, and you can keep `generatedbox` class when defining it. Then, you can omit the `div` that you had in the appended content.

```
  var tutorial = $('<div class="generatedbox">')
  $.each(data, function(){            
        tutorial.append($('<img src="images/tutorial_upload/' + this.thumbnail + '" /><h1>' + this.title + '</h1><p>' + this.summary + '</p><p class="date">' + this.created_at + '</p>'))
  });
```

Comment: This fixes the error however isn't effective for my needs as I must have a generated box for each iteration. This method throws everything in to a single generated box rather than multiple. The above answers worked better for my needs.